# Can I output a date in French from an XSL file?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, date-time, ddwrt

In my XSL file, I set my date like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@Date, 2057, 3)" />
```

This gives me an English date like `07 April 2015`. Can I get this date in French?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `2057` with `1036` (the LCID of `fr-FR`) and it should render the date in a French format.

The possible values for the third parameter, which control what type of date string is rendered, are listed in the MSDN blog post “[Custom Date Formats in SharePoint XSL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl.aspx)”.

Comment: Do you have a documentation on this? If i change it to 1036 i have the day  prepended to the date (i don't want it).

Comment: I've updated with a link to a good blog post. In short you will have to play with the third parameter to find the rendering that you want. Also if the rendering you want is not available with French local maybe som of the other examples in that link can get you what you want

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But... What a bad function... I can't format the date like a wanted to... There's only these values... 
1- 4/7/2015 12:00 AM ||
2- 07/04/2015 ||
4- mardi 7 avril 2015 ||
5- 00:00 ||
6- 07/04/2015 00:00 ||
8- mardi 7 avril 2015 00:00 ||
13- 00:00:00 ||
14- 07/04/2015 00:00:00 ||
16- mardi 7 avril 2015 00:00:00

Comment: Try ddwrt:FormatDateTime function... you'll be able to put in your custom format string. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583143(v=office.11).aspx#officesharepointddwrt_formatdatetime

Comment: Yeah it is a bit limited, as @jayhell says there are better functions if you know exactly how you want it formatted